# Add custom php postfix template to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: php, intellij-idea, code-completion

Is there any way to add custom postfix completion template for PHP language in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Postfix is a mail server, IntelliJ is a Java IDE and you're asking about PHP. I'm pretty sure you need to specify a lot more details to what you need

Comment: @apokryfos i mean postfix completion template. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way, unfortunately. Feel free to vote for or comment corresponding feature request at JetBrains tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27660